# Unexpected response from web service

Tags: android, json, coldfusion

I am not consuming the web services in Android for the first time, but with one of the web service, I am having a very strange issue.

Actually, there is an array that is being return in the jSon in response of the web service. If, in any case, that array contains 5 or less records, I get the response string as expected (with all the jSon). If the array contains more than 5 records, I start getting the empty string in response string from the server.

The same web Service is working fine on Poster, Postman, and on Hurl.it in all cases, even with 20 or more records in the array. (So, this doesn't seem to be a server side issue)

I have implemented several other APIs in the same android app and all others are work fine. Only this API shows unexpected behaviour.

Below I am pasting my Android side code and server side code (CF) that is involved in this web service.

The Server Side code is

```
<cffunction name="GetSuperAdmins" access="remote" returnType="struct" returnFormat="JSON">
  <cfargument name="ALID" type="string">
<cfif isdefined("url.alid")>
    <cfset alid = url.alid>
</cfif>
<cfif ALID eq '2'>
    <cfquery name="Super_Admins" datasource="#request.dsn#">
            SELECT userID,firstName,lastName
            FROM tUsers
            WHERE ALID = 2
            ORDER BY firstName ASC
     </cfquery>
     <cfquery name="distList" datasource="#request.dsn#">
            SELECT user_ids FROM tDistribution_users LIMIT 1
     </cfquery>
     <cfset user_ids =  distList.user_ids>
     <cfset result1 = {}>
     <cfset result1["success"] = "true">
     <cfset result1["SUPERADMINS"] = []>
     <cfloop query="Super_Admins">
            <cfset testObj = {}>
            <cfset dist = ListFind(user_ids, Super_Admins.userID)? 1:0>
            <cfset testObj["DISTRIBUTIONLISTED"] = "#dist#">
            <cfset testObj["FIRSTNAME"] = "#Super_Admins.firstName#">
            <cfset testObj["LASTNAME"] = "#Super_Admins.lastName#">
            <cfset testObj["USERID"] = "#Super_Admins.userID#">
            <cfset arrayAppend(result1["SUPERADMINS"], testObj)>
     </cfloop>

     <cfset result = result1>

<cfelse>
    <cfset msg = "Sorry! the given parameter is incorrect">
    <cfset result = '{"Success'&'":"false","msg'&'":"'&#msg#&'"}'>    
</cfif>
<cfreturn result>
```

And the Android Code for Getting the response is

```
public String postData(String val) throws IOException, IOException {
        String responseString;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("My_URL");

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alid","2"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            responseString = out.toString();
        } else{
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
        return responseString; 
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you Log `response.toString()` ?

Comment: Yes, are you checking the `responseString` itself, or are you checking the JSONObject after you create it? Just asking because sometimes people don't understand how to properly form JSONObjects and JSONArrays, so it's worth asking.

Comment: It Returns me this `""`

Comment: I am checking `responceString`

Comment: The response is an empty string. That is not a client-side issue, that's a server-side issue. If you are totally sure that it's an issue on the client, check if the parameters you're passing through your POST are correct; if the URL is correct and if you need any authentication to access this URL, as you're defining a brand new `HttpClient` just before posting data. If you had logged in or authenticated in any way to the server before, and thus retrieved a session or cookie, those would disappear if you re-declare the client.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I am pretty much sure that this is a client side issue because of two reasons. 1) The same API with same parameter is working fine on rest clients, like Hurl.it, Postman etc. 2) The API works good with the same Android code when the jSon should contain 5 or less records. As soon as I add the 6th record in the jSon array, I again start getting the empty string in `responsestring`.

Comment: Are you sure this line is correct? `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alid","2"));` Are these the key and values of your POST? Also, you pass a `String val` as argument. Why is that for?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso Yes, that's correct. Please see the line#2 of my server side code. You might not know the Coldfusion, but you can still see that the server side code is expecting a `String` type parameter with name `alid `.

Comment: I have no experience with Cf indeed. Is it case sensitive?

Comment: @RafealCardose CF is not case sensitive :)

Comment: I am not an Android developer, but if the same request works with other tools, that does suggest a client side issue. Have you tried a) logging the *raw* response with something like logcat? b) Have you tried other methods of consuming the response. A quick search suggests options like `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())`. c) Nothing to do with the issue, but once you fix the problem, there are a few areas of improvement in the CF code, ie variable scoping, localizing function variables, removing the manually constructed JSON (error message), etcetera.

Comment: @Leigh i have log the response but it also shows same result `""`

Comment: The *raw* response, right? As a sanity check a) log the request on the CF side so you can rule out any oddities in the http request. b) I know you said it works for other clients, but invoke the web service in your browser, with the same parameter, to verify it returns the expected string 3) Try a different method of consuming the response. A quick search of S.O. should turn up several options.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect form this part of your expression?

```
&#msg#&
```

Remove the # around your variable...

In any case you abuse the `&` in your statement.

Comment: In coldfusion a variable is wrapped within two `#`s. So `#msg#` in Coldfusion is equivalent to `$msg` in PHP.

Comment: And the `&` character is used for string concatenation in ColdFusion.

Comment: @AdilMalik: You are correct when you are using it inside the string, but outside the string - i.e. in the expression - it does direct substitution

Comment: @Miguel-F: I am aware of that, but you don't need to concatenate every few letters of the string...

Comment: That is true. Agreed.

Comment: @AdilMalik - Actually that whole section should be fixed (as I alluded above). Since the function uses `returnFormat=JSON`, you should not be constructing any part of the response manually. At best it is unnecessary. At worst, it could cause the result to be double serialized. Instead, create CF structures, just as you are doing with the query results.  (That said, you could also remove returnFormat from the function signature. Then when you need JSON, simply append `?returnformat=json` to the request URL).

Comment: @Leigh OK, I'll try your suggested solutions and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue as i stuck on it.
just write this line of code after your httpPost request

```
httppost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "text/plain");
```

Enjoy and thanks for all the buddies who respond on my question for me.